# Order posts by popularity based on date submitted and views

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

The way I am currently trying to sort rows(posts) in the database by popularity is by dividing the timestamp submitted by the number views the post has and then order them in ascending order.

my table looks like below

```
ID      submitted             views

1  2013-09-03 15:14:05          1

2  2013-09-04 11:13:54          2

3  2013-09-05 18:14:13          3

4  2013-09-06 12:05:05          4
```

I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY SUM(unix_timestamp(submitted)/views) ASC LIMIT 30
```

however it only gives 1 result when I have nearly 40 posts

I have also tried it without the sum function

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY unix_timestamp(submitted)/views ASC LIMIT 30
```

but all this seems to do is display them posts in order of just views in descending order which is really weird because I have stated ASC.

If is helps in any way I am using PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you want to order them by the difference between `now()` and the submitted time, divided by views.  This roughly measures the average number of views per unit time, a measure that makes sense to me:

```
ORDER BY (unix_timestamp(now()) - unix_timestamp(submitted)) / views ASC
```

This would return the posts by the ones that have the highest frequency of views.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY views ASC
```

is this not working ?

Comment: that's not calculating popularity... that simply places them in order of views furthermore from lowest to highest views...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your query is correct and it is correctly ordering the data, see the timestamp column :

```
SELECT *, unix_timestamp(submitted)/views As timestamp FROM posts ORDER BY 
unix_timestamp(submitted)/views ASC LIMIT 30;
```

See this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a8f4/11

You should change your logic.